# What is the correct word / words for the information about someone's body, like hip circumference?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to find a suitable word, that summarises data like different body parts' circumferences. What I could think of is 'Body Information', but it sounds bad at least for my non-native ears, and I don't know whether there is something better.

Comment: I would migrate this to [our sister site for learners of the language](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but since it can simply be looked up in a bilingual dictionary of your choosing I have to go with general reference.

Answer (score 2):

You would usually refer to a person's *measurements*. A woman's bust, waist and hip measurements are also informally called *[vital statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bust-waist-hip_measurements)*.